# .NET Make second ajax call after success of first

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've got 2 ajax calls to go to 2 separate controller methods, one to create a floorplan object and save it to the database, the other sends an array of any  plan objects (chairs, tables etc.) to the same database.

I have the second ajax call within the success of the first call, however it seems to not occur initially. I have set up breakpoints to check the data, and a floorplan is definitely added with valid data. If I attempt to create another, it works then, so I'm not sure if it is a database issue or if my JavaScript is wrong.

This is the ajax calls I have for my JavaScript save function

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Floorplans/Create",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify($floorplan),
    success: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/planObjects/Create",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify($objArray)
            //objArray is an array of planObjects
        });

}
});
```

My floorplan  controller:

```
[HttpPost]
//Floorplan controller
    public ActionResult Create(Floorplan floorplan)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid){
                db.Floorplans.Add(floorplan);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new {success = true});
            }
            else{
                return Json(new {success = false});
            }



    }
```

planObjects controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Create(List<planObject> newObjects)
    {
        var model = new planObject();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            newObjects.ForEach(r => db.planObjects.Add(r));
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

With this code, the ajax call within the success of the first ajax call is not executed on first attempt, but if I make another floorplan it works perfectly. Can you guys see a fix to the problem? I was attempting to use a single controller action method but I was unable to get it working correctly.

Comment: FYI: `success` in json won't affect success callback conditionally. Inside your `success` callback you need to put `success: function (data) { if (data.success){.....}`

Comment: tip: consider the promise API for nested calls, it improves the readability a lot!

Comment: @Curt Thanks for the tip, you helped me solve my problem along with SBirthare's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code a bit (I could make it work locally). I suspect it could be the "data" element in second call causing the trouble. I would check the progress step by step and go from there.

If you add some alert or log messages like below, what do you see?

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "FloorPlans")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify($floorplan),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success) {
                Log("Floor plan created successfully, adding plan objects...");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "PlanObjects")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify($objArray),
                    //objArray is an array of planObjects
                    success: function(result2) {
                        if (result2.success) {
                            Log("Plan objects created successfully");
                        } else {
                            Log("Failed to create plan objects");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log("Failed to add floor plan");
            }
        }
    });

    function Log(data) {
        //alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on how to check through it. Turns out I had a window relocation to another view and this seemed to occur before the response came back so it never reached the inner call.